# How to replace spaces in all file names with underscore in Linux using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, files, find, rename, mv

I tried following shell script which should replace spaces from all xml filenames

```
for xml_file in $(find $1 -name "* .xml" -type f);
do
 echo "removing spaces from XML file:" $xml_file
 mv "$xml_file" "${xml_file// /_}";
done
```

Suppose, I have xml file with the name `xy z.xml`, then it gives:

```
removing spaces from XML file: /home/krishna/test/xy
mv: cannot stat `/home/krishna/test/xy': No such file or directory
removing spaces from XML file: .xml
mv: cannot stat `z.xml': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use this with `bash`:

```
find $1 -name "* *.xml" -type f -print0 | \
  while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
```

`find` will search for files with a space in the name. The filenames will be printed with a nullbyte (`-print0`) as delimiter to also cope with special filenames.
Then the `read` builtin reads the filenames delimited by the nullbyte and finally `mv` replaces the spaces with an underscore.

**EDIT:** If you want to remove the spaces in the directories too, it's a bit more complicated. The directories are renamed and then not anymore accessible by the name `find` finds. Try this:

```
find -name "* *" -print0 | sort -rz | \
  while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "${f// /_}")"; done
```

The `sort -rz` reverses the file order, so that the deepest files in a folder are the first to move and the folder itself will be the last one. So, there are never folders renamed before all files and folder are rename inside of it. The `mv` command in the loop is a bit changed too. In the target name, we only remove the spaces in the basename of the file, else it wouldn't be accessible.

Comment: I am trying to replace spaces with underscore in all directory but it is giving error because after changing name that directory is not accessible.

Comment: @krishna I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: @chaos wow, just ran these two on two systems and it worked like a charm, few files and dirs not going through but it's only a few

Comment: On macOS we need to specify the directory in the find command before the -name option

`find . -name "* *" -print0 | sort -rz | \
  while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "${f// /_}")"; done`

Comment: Could this solution applied to remove a specific patterns from the file name like `-_-`?

Comment: @alpher Yes of course ! Just like this: `find -name "*-_-*" -print0 | sort -rz | while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "${f//-_-/}")"; done`

Answer (score 33):

1. Using `rename`

   ```
   find . -type f -name "* *.xml" -exec rename "s/\s/_/g" {} \;
   ```

   or with `$1`

   ```
   find "$1" -type f -name "* *.xml" -exec rename "s/\s/_/g" {} \;
   ```
2. Using `mv`

   ```
   find . -type f -name "* *.xml" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0// /_}"' {} \;
   ```

   or with `$1`

   ```
   find "$1" -type f -name "* *.xml" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0// /_}"' {} \;
   ```

Comment: I don't know why but your given command is not working for me. It is not showing any error and output.

Comment: @krishna corrected, sorry

Comment: Rename worked for me. Fistbump!

Answer (score 7):

This is a method I found while facing the same problem:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" `echo $f | tr ' ' '_'`; done
```

I was writing a bash script file to automatically update my ssl certificates.

Answer (score 7):

Use `rename`:

```
rename 's/\s/_/g' ./*.xml
```

No need for `find` :)

Comment: add the trailing g to the regex and it works perfectly. 's/\s/_/g'

Comment: Good tip, thanks :)