# How to remove space in all sub directories in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, find, directory, rename, mv

I tried following shell script to remove all spaces with underscores:

```
find $1 -depth -name "* *" -print0 | \
while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
```

If I have a directory `/home/user/g h/y h/u j/` it will modify `y h` directory to `y_h` and then it will give an error for `/home/user/g h/y h/u j`:

```
No such file or directory
```

Comment: See my edit in you previous question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223185/52727

Comment: Start with renaming the deepest directory first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539583/how-do-i-recursively-list-all-directories-at-a-location-breadth-first how to generate such a list of (sub)directories

Comment: This has been discussed more than once, just search under the [`/rename`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rename) tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
find -name "* *" -print0 | sort -rz | \
  while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "${f// /_}")"; done
```

`find` will search for files and folders with a space in the name. This will be printed (`-print0`) with nullbytes as delimiters to cope with special filenames too.

The `sort -rz` reverses the file order, so that the deepest files in a folder are the first to move and the folder itself will be the last one. So, there are never folders renamed before all files and folder are rename inside of it.

Finally, the `mv` command renames the file/folder. In the target name, we only remove the spaces of the files basename, else it wouldn't be accessible anymore.

Comment: `find: illegal option -- n`, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
find $1 -depth -name "* *" -type d -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

separate between filename `basename` (i.e. last name in the path) and `dirname`:

```
find $1 -depth -name "* *" -print0 | \
while read -d $'\0' f ; do
    a="$(dirname "$f")"
    b="$(basename "$f")"
    #optional check if the basename changes -> reduces errors in mv command
    #only needed when using -wholename instead of -name in find, so skippable
    if [ "${b// /_}" != "$b" ] ; then
      mv -v "$a"/"$b"  "$a"/"${b// /_}"
    fi
done
```

The problem of first changing subdirs before changing higher dirs is already taken care of with the `-depth` specification in `find`.