# awk to match and cut out fields with alternating delimiter

Tags: shell-script, awk

[image: example bookmarks file]

I would like to use `awk` or similar to match patterns of a chrome bookmarks file and depending on match, cut out a specific field based on different field delimiters.

I have attached a sample picture. I still haven't figured out how to attach as a file.

I want the folder names in case the string `H3` is matched and the URL in case the string `HREF` is encountered.

the following two commands do the job for the respective matches:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '/H3/{print $5}' bookmarks.htm
awk -F'"' '/HREF/{print $2}' bookmarks.html
```

My goal is to combine the two statements above so the output becomes:

```
UNIX
url-1
url-2
OCE
url-3
url-4
url-5
ANDROID
url-6
url-7
```

I have tried `awk`'s if, then, else but wasn't conclusive.

How do I achieve this as a one-liner? are there better candidates than `awk`? python, perl would both be great, however, one-liner is an absolute as it would be an easy task writing a shell script that does the job.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text, paste the *actual text*...

Comment: text is very long and ugly formatting. i tcan't be added as it contians URLs and as a beginner i am not allowed > 1 URL in my post

Comment: Use the `{}` button to format the text as code.

Comment: the {} produced something that looks like only a partial code extract -> no good

Comment: You don't need a one-liner to make it easy to script, but here is one anyway: `awk -F'[<>]' '/<H3/{print $5} /HREF="/{sub(/[^"]*"/,"");sub(/".*/,"");print}' bookmark.html`

Comment: dave_thompson_085, if you add that comment as answer i will mark it as correct. please if you have time also add annotations how to read the awk command. parts of are clear to me but not all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong way to process html-files with **sed**/**awk**/… There are few special parsers but as temporary substitution

```
sed '
    /\n/{P;d;}
    /<H3/s/[><]/\n/4g
    /HREF/s/"/\n/g
    D
    ' bookmarks.htm
```

For non-GNU versions of **sed**:

```
sed '
    /\n/{P;d;}     #if there is more then 1 line «P»rint 1st line then «d»elete all
    /<\/H3/s//\n/  #replace «</H3» by «\n»ewline
    /\n/s/">/\n/   #replace «">» by «\n»ewline if previous command is executed
    /HREF/s/"/\n/g #put «\n»ewline» around url if «HREF» in line
    D              #«D»elete 1 first line, go to start
    ' bookmarks.htm
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives the urls but not the headers, trying to adapt the part:  /<H3/s/[><]/\n/4g

Comment: @HenrikJson It possible if you use non-GNU sed: `4g` construction is not recognized. In the case you have to substitute it by `/<\/H3/s//\n/;/\n/s/">/\n/`

Comment: Costas, if you add that comment + your original command as answer i will mark it as correct. please if you have time also add annotations how to read the sed command. parts of are clear to me but not all

Comment: @HenrikJson see updated

Answer (score 1):

Using a xml / html parser / processor has some advantages. **Xpath** expressions are the standard way to select specific parts.

#### xml + xmlstarlet + xpath

If the input is well formed xml we can use xmlstarlet + xpath expression:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//h3|//a/@href' -nl bookmarks.html
```

#### html + xmllint : xml

If the input is just valid html, we can convert it to xml (using **xmllint**) and use the previous:

```
xmllint -html -xmlout ex.html | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//h3|//a/@href' -nl -
```

#### xmllint + xpath

We can use xmllint + xpath expression, directly

```
xmllint -html -xpath '//h3/text()|//a/@href' bookmarks.html
```

... but the output format is not the same...

Comment: Could you explain what this is ?

Comment: @DarkHeart, I added some more information.

Comment: on the cygwin I am running, neither xmllint nor xpath available

Comment: @HenrikJson, you can install both xmllint (`setup-x86_64 -qP libxml2`) and xmlstarlet in cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

One last answer: this time a one-ligner perl

```
perl -nE 'say $1 if (/<h3.*?>(.*?)<\/h3>/i or /href="(.*?)"/i)' ex.html
```

(I believe that xml parser based solutions are better, but since you have a
tool-generated file, the amount of surprises should not be very high)

Answer (score 0):

For now I discarded demand for one-liner and did it as a script instead.

I had to post this as a response as it would have been too long for a comment. Still, feel free to respond.

This script does the job but is too sluggish, can anyone speed it up or alternatively suggest a one-liner?

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$1
while IFS= read -r line
do
hdr=$(echo $line | awk -F'[<>]' '/H3/{print $5}')
url=$(echo $line | awk -F'"' '/HREF/{print $2}')
if [ ${url} ]; then
    echo $url
elif [ ${hdr} ]; then
    echo $hdr
fi
done <"$file"
```

Here the file: (finally got it)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
  <h1>Bookmarks</h1>
  <dl>
    <dd>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1484311924" LAST_MODIFIED="1485532328">UNIX</H3>
      <dl>
        <dt><a HREF="http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223182/how-to-replace-spaces-in-all-file-names-with-underscore-in-linux-using-shell-scr" add_date="1484311897">url-1</a></dt>
        <dt><a HREF="http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81349/how-do-i-use-find-when-the-filename-contains-spaces"        add_date="1484738308">url-2</a></dt>
      </dl>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1486550854" LAST_MODIFIED="1487228526">OCE</H3>
      <dl>
        <dt><a HREF="http://www.oraclecertificationprep.com/apex/f?p=OCPSG%3AEXAM_DETAILS%3A%3A%3ANO%3A%3AP2_EXAM%3A1Z0-061"    add_date="1486550866">url-3</a></dt>
        <dt><a HREF="http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=303&amp;p_certName=SQ1Z0_047" add_date="1486550898">url-4</a></dt>
        <dt><a HREF="https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prepare-for-an-Oracle-Database-SQL-exam" add_date="1486550950">url-5</a></dt>
      </dl>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1487084050" LAST_MODIFIED="1487228595">ANDROID</H3>
      <dl>
        <dt><a HREF="https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#" add_date="1487228526">url-6</a></dt>
        <dt><a HREF="https://developer.android.com/index.html" add_date="1487228539">url-7</a></dt>
      </dl>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</body>
</html>
```